# Predictive mode Emacs

Tags: emacs

I installed predictive mode in emacs. After doing `M-x predictive-mode` I get the following error

```
Symbol's function definition is void: run-hook-wrapped
```

and I can no longer type in the buffer. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm . . . the function `run-hook-wrapped` is written in C and is included in a current version of Emacs Trunk -- `eval.c`.  My best guess is that you have an old version of Emacs, or the Emacs installation has been damaged and will need to be reinstalled.  My recommendation would be to upgrade your Emacs installation to the latest stable public release, or try out a snapshot developer build of the experimental version.

Comment: Following up on what @lawlist wrote: Check the file header (Commentary) of the Predictive file(s), to see if you can find out what Emacs versions it requires.  There might be, for example, a `Compatibility` spec in the header.  If necessary, contact [Toby Cubitt](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TobyCubitt), the author of Predictive mode.  He should be able to tell you what is minimally required. (But try first to find this info in the Predictive files.)